# Using includes for layouts in xkb config

Tags: xkb

I created a new layout, it's for a new set of glyphs and keycodes that do not exist in Unicode yet, I was able to create a working layout, but I was asked not to merge it upstream, as since it's not in Unicode, it may require changes and having it essentially everywhere is a big change.
This is my merge request:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/kohen.d/xkeyboard-config/-/merge_requests/2
I want to make it an independent package with minimal changes, but when adding the layout to the xml and putting the layout as a separate file to be included from the base layout, GNOME doesn't seem to see the layout.
I guess I may need to refer to the file somewhere else to have it known, but where and how?
All the relevant documentation I found does not seem to talk about this.